# gdb print different in 32bits and 64bits

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am just doing a simple thing 
`p/d 0xffffffff` on my 64 bits ubuntu gdb, it gives me a positive number
but if I type `p/d 0xffffffff` it gives me `-1`.

This is kind of annoying because I am working on a 32 bits project. I have to add a bunch of `f` everytime.

Any setting can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 64-bit:

```
(gdb) p/d (int)0xffffffff
$11 = -1
(gdb) p/d (long)0xffffffff
$12 = 4294967295
```

On 32-bit:

```
(gdb) p/d (int)0xffffffff
$1 = -1
(gdb) p/d (long)0xffffffff
$2 = -1
```